# Low Throughput of AWS Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-kinesis

I use python's [`boto.kinesis`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/kinesis.html) module to write records to [AWS Kinesis](http://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/). The maximum throughput that is reached is about 40 puts/sec. However, according to the [Kinesis FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/faqs/):

> Each shard can support up to 1000 PUT records per second.

So my current approach **reaches only 4%** what is theoretically possible, which seems terribly low.

Does anyone have an idea how the throughput can be improved?

Setup: The Kinesis Stream is an instance with one shard. The producer is on a dedicated AWS EC2 instance (t3.medium) in the same region as the Kinesis Stream. It creates strings of about 20 characters lengths and sends them to the Kinesis Stream via `boto.kinesis.Connection.put_record("my_stream", my_message)`.

Simplified code:

```
from boto import kinesis
import time

connection = kinesis.connect_to_region(REGION)
stream = connection.create_stream("my_stream", shard_count=1)
time.sleep(60)  # wait a minute until stream is created

for i in range(NUM_MESSAGES): 
    my_message = "This is message %d" % i
    connection.put_record(my_message, "my_stream", "partition_key")
```

Comment: Have you tried using the bulk method, ``put_records``?  Each HTTP call to the service involves a lot of overhead so putting as much data as you can per call will help improve throughput.  Also, are you doing the loading from an EC2 instance within the same region?  That would also help.

Comment: @garnaat: Yes, I bulked them together to send 100 messages at a time via `connection.put_records(message_list, "my_stream")`, with `message_list.append({'Data': my_message, 'PartitionKey': str(i)})`. However, the throughput even **drops** to 30 puts/sec.

Comment: You mean 30 puts of 100 records per second?

Comment: I found a bug in my code. After the fix, the messages are now really bulked together. Result: 17 puts/sec, i.e. **1700 msg/sec**. That makes a lot more sense. Thanks for your help @garnaat.

Comment: Can you share what was the bug.. or update the code in the question. It will be helpful to the readers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html

The limit is for records/second
you should use putRecords to improve write throughput. the way you do that is that you place multiple records inside the same call. so you keep appending and the end you do the put records.

also
take a look at: https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-poster-worker

Comment: I tried that, but the throughput went down. (See the comment in the OP).

Comment: I fixed a bug in my code and the throughput is now up to 1700 msg/sec. Your suggestion was absolutely correct. Thanks. (See my comment in OP)

Comment: we use fluentd to capture, aggregate and push events to kinesis